# start/stop .sh file for .jar file

Tags: centos

I have a file JTS3ServerMod.jar that i want to be able to start and stop via ssh (centos) so the command would basically be ./JTS3ServerMod.jar {start|stop|restart}

how would i do this? I tried to look at how the teamspeak startscript work but was not able to convert that from starting a binary to a .jar file.

Comment: What specifically is your problem? Do you not know how to use ssh? Do you not know how to run a jar on linux?

Comment: I am trying to create a .sh file that will allow me to start,stop and restart the jar file. I can start the jar file im just unsure how to make the script that would allow me to start,stop or restart the jar file

Comment: How does ssh relate to writing a script to start a jar?

Comment: Sorry what i ment is im running the script via ssh my wording was poor. All im trying to create is a start/stop/restart script for a jar file and am having a hard time doing so